# How to only have selected 1 checkbox in a Ngx-datable table?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngx-datatable

I have an  ngx-datatable witch checkboxes, only 1 checkbox needs should be selected at a time.

I have tried to  accesing the event using this:

html

```
 <ngx-datatable 
  class="margin-left bootstrap" 
  [rows]="rows" 
  [loadingIndicator]="'true'" 
  [rowHeight]="'30'"
  [reorderable]="'true'" 
  [scrollbarH]="'true'" 
  [columnMode]="'standard'" 
  [columns]="columns"
  [selectionType]="'checkbox'"
  [selectAllRowsOnPage]="false"
  (select)='onSelect($event)'>    
  </ngx-datatable>
```

But the event only contain what is selected. Would there be a way to unselect everything but the last checkbox clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swimlane offers an example on how to clear all selections [here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/app/selection/selection-chkbox.component.ts) with a demo [here](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#chkbox-selection). Notice the "remove" button at the top of the page.

The main points are utilizing the @Inputs `[selected]` and updating your @Output `(select)`.

**component.html**

```
 <ngx-datatable 
  class="margin-left bootstrap" 
  [rows]="rows" 
  [loadingIndicator]="'true'" 
  [rowHeight]="'30'"
  [reorderable]="'true'" 
  [scrollbarH]="'true'" 
  [columnMode]="'standard'" 
  [columns]="columns"
  [selectionType]="'checkbox'"
  [selectAllRowsOnPage]="false"
  (select)='onSelect($event)'>    
  </ngx-datatable>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent {

  selected = [];


  onSelect({ selected }) {
    this.selected = [];
    this.selected.push(...selected);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the value `radio` instead of checkbox. Example:

```
<ngx-datatable 
  class="margin-left bootstrap" 
  [rows]="rows" 
  [loadingIndicator]="'true'" 
  [rowHeight]="'30'"
  [reorderable]="'true'" 
  [scrollbarH]="'true'" 
  [columnMode]="'standard'" 
  [columns]="columns"
  [selectionType]="'radio'"
  [selectAllRowsOnPage]="false">    
  </ngx-datatable>
```